# [three.js toggle through models using GUI

Tags: javascript, three.js

I some models in my scene and using dat.gui I would like to be able to toggle through the different models.

So far I have tried doing this by changing the visibility on/off using this code:

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();

var controls = {

toggleObjects: function(){
g3white.traverse(function(child){child.visible = true;});
g3black.traverse(function(child){child.visible = false;});
}

};

gui.add(controls, 'toggleObjects');
```

However, I keep getting errors that break my code: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Additionally, I would like to have more than 2 models and at the click of a button that model displays and all the other are hidden.

Is this the best/easiest way to go about this or is there something else I should do?

Any help is appreciated, I'm sort of a three.js beginner.

Comment: It's hard to say, but I would guess "traverse" is not defined on either g3white, g3blac or both. If you are using chrome - i would suggest you use DevTools and enable breaking on uncaught exceptions; button looks like this: (ii)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have defined traverse on both objects as: 
g3white.traverse(function(child){
    child.visible = true;
 });

Answer (score 1):

You should be traversing the scene, checking if child is the object you want and then turning on/off visibility.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673937/three-js-how-to-access-items-inside-scene-should-i-use-document-getelementbyid.